# SELECT COUNT в цикле

Tags: php, mysql, запрос

Есть 2 таблицы: news и comments. Как посчитать количество комментариев к каждой новости?

```
SELECT `news`.`name`,`news`.`text` (
    SELECT COUNT(1) 
      FROM `comments` 
     WHERE `comments`.`news_id`=`news`.`id`) AS `comments` 
      FROM  `news`,`comments`
```

Так у всех новостей количество комментариев равняется кол-ву комментариев у первой новости.

Comment: ?

    SELECT `news`.`name`,`news`.`text`
    FROM news join (SELECT news_id, COUNT(*) FROM `comments`
       GROUP BY news_id) a on news.id = a.news_id

Comment: FROM  `news`, `comments`

`comments` -  лишнее. И запятая в условии пропущена. Исправите - будет считать.

Comment: @Равнодушный перемести комментарий в ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Такой вариант подойдет?

```
SELECT n.name, n.text, Count(c.id) as comments
FROM news n
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.news_id = n.id
GROUP BY n.id
```